# Create JAX WS Web Service that Response XML using Netbeans

Tags: service

I'm  newbie at web service stuff,

I have following the tutorial at https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html

Now I want to create web service (like that tutorial) but it return a XML.

How I can build that?
Thank you for the answer

Comment: You mean converting a Web Service to XML ? You should write your own logic